# Android - Move button to bottom in layout

Tags: c#, android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I'm having some issues with align my button to the bottom of my layout. Look this picture:

[image: Image Layout]

As you can see I need this 5 button to be at the bottom of my layout. How can I do that? I tried layout gravity to bottom but it doesn't work. This is my code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@android:color/background_light"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="100">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_weight="80">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="25"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="- How much wood would a woodchuck chuck if a woodchuck could chuck wood?"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
        android:paddingTop="20dp"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp" />
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnA"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:text="YOLO"
        android:maxHeight="60dp"
        android:minHeight="60dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textSize="10dp"
        android:background="@android:color/background_dark"
        android:layout_margin="10dp" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnB"
        android:text=" asda sdas dasd asd asasdasdaCiaoaga gaerg aergae gr earg aerg aerg "
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textSize="10dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/background_dark"
        android:layout_margin="10dp" />
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnC"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:text="James Bond"
        android:maxHeight="60dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:minHeight="60dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textSize="10dp"
        android:background="@android:color/background_dark"
        android:layout_margin="10dp" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnD"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:text="Dunno"
        android:maxHeight="60dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:minHeight="60dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textSize="10dp"
        android:background="@android:color/background_dark"
        android:layout_margin="10dp" />
</LinearLayout>
<Button
    android:text="Change"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/btnCambia"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_dark" />
```

Comment: Hey, what do you want exactly? Explain me in detail so I can guide you.

Comment: So you need asda button besides James bond button and Dunno button besides YOLO? Am I right?

Comment: I need all button below TextView to be at the bottom of my app

Comment: means which textview? Blue one?

Comment: Yes, I need all the button (Yolo, james bond, asdasdsa, Dude, Change) to be at the bottom

Comment: @ParthBhayani can you help?

Comment: Yes, I do, but before that I need to ask you something that you need all four button below CHANGE button or all five buttons comes to the bottom?

Answer (score 0):

you can add them to a different layout and set

```
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:gravity="bottom"
```

Comment: So I have to create an other layout inside linearlayout?

Comment: i meant to create another linear layout (or whatever kind  of layout you used) inside the linear layout

Answer (score 0):

Add an empty view between textview's linearlayout and buttons' linear layout like this :

```
<View
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your main linearlayout tag in a relativelayout and then set alignparentbottom as true for the linearlayout.